# Product list filter by custom attribute

Tags: product-collection, product-list

In the code that I'm working has a filter by a custom attribute. When the value is true the product must disappear but there is a bug. When I go to a Product list page (grid) and there is a product when the value is true, a gap is showing up with a empty place.

I tried to get the class when the toolbar split the collection but I'm only getting the already split collection

`vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Layer.php`